# How to run several tests in rspec

Tags: ruby, linux, testing, rspec, automation

I run several tests via rspec. The names are `test1.rb`, `test2.rb`, and so on. How do I run all of them in a queue and not one by one in the linux console? I tried an

```
rspec -e"test"
```

variant, but the console says all examples were filtered out. Please help.

Comment: I think all specs file have to be like: test1_spec.rb and test2_spec.rb i.e. `_spec` at the end in filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I proceed, please note that all specs filename should end with `_spec.rb`.  In your case it should be: `test1_spec.rb`, `test2_spec.rb`, and so on.  I'd encourage you to checkout [RSpec documentation on command line usage](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line). To run all specs which are inside `./spec` directory. You can run:

```
$ rspec .
```

You can pass [`--order`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/order) option to run all specs in random order: `$ rspec --order rand`. If you want to run particular spec files then you can pass `path/to/your/file`:

```
$ rspec spec/test1_spec.rb spec/test2_spec.rb
```

Please check [`-e` or `--example`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-1/docs/command-line/example-option) command option, which runs the specs with description passed as argument to `-e` option for more clarity.